# How to post data from android apps using android studio to the server

Tags: android, json, post, server, backend

This Android app is using Android Studio. The function is to scan and display data from the beacon/eddystone. The app already functions and after the scanning stops, the data saves to the local file. But my problem is when I have to transfer the scanning data to the server, I have to ent it to the back-end server. But I really didn't know what is the best way as I'm a beginner.

Here is the code that the data will transfer to the local data:

```
private void stopScanning(Button scanButton) {
    try {
        beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO - OK, what now then?
    }
    String scanData = logString.toString();
    if (scanData.length() > 0)
    {
        // Write file
        fileHelper.createFile(scanData);
        // Display file created message.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "File saved to:" + getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        scanButton.setText(MODE_STOPPED);
    } else {
        // We didn't get any data, so there's no point writing an empty file.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "No data captured during scan, output file will not be created.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        scanButton.setText(MODE_STOPPED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use volley or retrofit library for connections to server, for sending data to server or fetching data from server http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en  http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/training/volley/index.html

Comment: I recommend studying retrofit (also rxandroid but this is optional) http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: how do you want to receive the data in the server? as JSON, XML, query parameters, upload the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send Data to a server there are many ways, BUT I PREFER you use Volley Library because it's faster and easier

You can use volley for fetching and sending data ,For example:

```
   //Request serever for JsonObject
  JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            //Your code to proceed with fetched data

          }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }){
              //This is the method used to put params into the body, this what you will have to use for sending post data
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

              params.put("name","jois");
            return params;
        }

    };

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(request);




compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' This is the dependice you will have to add in build.gradle file to use volley library
```

I hope this was helpful, ThankYou

Comment: if i am using volley for sending data, did i need a web service? or i just can directly send to the url server?

Comment: You can send through URL or use web service! U cab do both